# White screen after Splash in iOS application after Upgrading to WKWebView Ionic 3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview

I have upgraded my application to WKWebView by following [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/) blog. If i make a build using ionic cordova build ios it runs normally but if i make a --prod build then my app is getting stuck after splash screen and a white screen shows up. I have read many threads regarding the same and found similar issues.

I have tried the following plugins -

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save
, cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr
```

but still the problem exists.

Here is my config.xml-

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
     <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/default-landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/default-portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="216" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-108@2x.png" width="216" />
        <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2688h~iphone.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2688h~iphone.png" width="2688" />
        <splash height="1792" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1792h~iphone.png" width="828" />
        <splash height="828" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-1792h~iphone.png" width="1792" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
    </platform>
```

How to make this work?
Help is really appreciated as i am stuck with this issue since 2 days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hassle, I found out the issue was different on the prod build. I was getting a `cannot find module '.'` error due to Typescript version mismatch which was causing the blank white screen. When i degraded the TS version I was able to make a prod build.

Posting for the people if they come across the same issue in the future.

Thanks!